# Django: TemplateSyntaxError, Invalid filter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filters

I'm trying to access a value from a dictionary using a variable, all in an HTML file that follows Django's Templating language. Django's templating language doesn't let you access a dictionary using a variable as a key, so I decided to use Django filters to do it. However, I am getting a "Invalid filter" error and I can't figure out why.

My html file

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Username</th>
        <th scope="row">Full Name</th>
        <th scope="row">Points</th>
        {% for subject in subjects %}
        <th scope="row">{{ subject }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'profile' username=user.username %}">{{ user.username }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.profile.points.total }}</td>
        {% for subject in subjects %}
        <td>{{ user.profile.points|keyvalue:subject }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

My filter.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def keyvalue(dict, key):    
    return dict[key]
```

My error message

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /leaderboard/
Invalid filter: 'keyvalue'
```

Thank you for any help :D

EDIT: Pasting my views.py and urls.pu as requested

views.py

```
def leaderboard(request):
    global leaderboard_public
    users = sorted(User.objects.all(), key=lambda t: t.profile.points['total'], reverse=True)

    if request.method == "POST":
        leaderboard_public = not leaderboard_public
        return redirect(leaderboard)
    subjects = list(Subject.objects.values('subject_name'))
    subjects = [i['subject_name'] for i in subjects]
    print(subjects)
    return render(request, "leaderboard.html", {
        "users": users,
        "subjects": subjects,
        # "leaderboard_public": leaderboard_public,
    })
```

urls.py

```
from accounts import views as accountsViews
from puzzles import views as puzzlesViews

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

url(r'^signup/$', accountsViews.signup_without_email, name="signup"),
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    accountsViews.activate, name='activate'),
url(r'^logout/$', authViews.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
url(r'^login/$', authViews.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name="login"),
# url(r'^puzzles/$', puzzlesViews.puzzles, name="puzzles"),
url(r'^puzzle/(?P<puzzleID>.+)/edit/$', puzzlesViews.editPuzzle, name="editPuzzle"),
url(r'^puzzle/(?P<puzzleID>.+)/$', puzzlesViews.puzzle, name="puzzle"),
url(r'^scheduled/$', puzzlesViews.scheduled, name="scheduled"),
url(r'^closed/$', puzzlesViews.closed, name="closed"),
url(r'^leaderboard/$', accountsViews.leaderboard, name="leaderboard"),
# url(r'^leaderboard/(?P<subject>.+)/$', accountsViews.leaderboard_subject, name="leaderboard"),
# url(r'^submissions/$', puzzlesViews.submissions, name="submissions"),
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>.+)/submissions$', puzzlesViews.submissions, name="submissions"),
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>.+)/edit/$', accountsViews.editProfile, name="editProfile"),
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>.+)/$', accountsViews.profile, name="profile"),
url(r'^create/$', puzzlesViews.create, name="create"),
# url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
url(r'^$', puzzlesViews.puzzles, name="puzzles"),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Let me know if there's any other information needed.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Everything looks okay. At least, the problem is not on the code/files you are showing. What's the Python and Django version you are working with? Did you placed the `filter.py` file inside a valid Django app? The app where you created the `filter.py` is listed in the `INSTALLED_APS`? Is the folder called *exactly* `templatetags`? Do you have a `__init__.py` file inside that folder? Are you calling `{% load filter %}` *before* this line `{{ user.profile.points|keyvalue:subject }}`?

Answer (score 7):

I tried `{% load crispy_forms_filters %}` and it worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

Using both [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) and other users' answers, here's everything I had to do in order for it to work

1. Create a folder called **templatetags**
2. Create a **filter.py** file inside it

- I also created an **init**.py file, but it's probably not necessary in Python 3+

3. In **setting.py** file inside the root folder, I added the following

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'templatetags.filter']

    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            **'libraries':{
                'filter': 'templatetags.filter',**
            }
        },
    },
    ]
```

4. Inside the new created **filter.py**, I defined my filter

```
    import datetime
    from django import template
    
    register = template.Library()
    
    @register.filter(name="my_filter_name")
    def my_filter_name(input):
        output = do_something_with_input(input)
        return output
    
    register.filter('my_filter_name', my_filter_name)
```

5. Load the **filter** (configured in the previous steps) inside my html template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load filter %}

...
```

Obs: Django's documentation seems not to be the best documentation I've seen in a while. In fact, it should contain many more examples and be clearer.

I hope this helps anyone fiddling around Django :)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to:
improve text arragement (no headings without reason)
.

See [answer]

Comment: I have done all of this. And this solution will always give an error "invalid template library specified"...

Comment: That's great. I was stuck in `tojson` filter issue. I created mine and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you forget to load `filter.py` model into template. To use custom filters you need to put `filter.py` inside `app/templatetags` directory (note this directory should include `__init__.py`) and load it in template using syntax `{% load filter %}`. See documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: It's my bad because I haven't posted my entire HTML file, but I have loaded filter and I have done all the peripheral setup for filters as per the documentation. In fact, I have used a different filter in a different HTML file (in the same app) and that works fine. It seems that for some reason something is wrong with this specific filter, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @ohjuny did you restart django after adding this new filter?

Comment: yes I have tried restarting my django server. It still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ohjuny hm.. do you have `{% load filter %}` tag in this specific template? This tag should be used in every template. Also can you check if it is some typo in for example file names? Because I checked your filter it works with my test project.

Comment: Well, that's weird. I also tested it locally -- just copied and pasted OPs filter and it worked normally...

Comment: with which database models will a custom filter work? It isn't specified in the manual. It is not working with IntegerField