# Django 'jsonify' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Tags: django, heroku, django-templates, django-template-filters, jsonify

I am working on a django project where Installed a package called jsonify which is to be used in the django template from https://pypi.org/project/jsonify/ & added in the installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "jsonify",
    "main",
]
```

In my local environment it works just fine but when I deployed to heroku I keep

> 'jsonify' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
> admin_list
> admin_modify
> admin_urls
> cache
> i18n
> l10n
> log
> static
> to_and
> tz

Also note I have also made my own custom template tag "to_and" which works perfectly fine. This only happens in production in heroku and not in my local envirnoment. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you followed this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/47085113/14457833 and please read this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42881074/14457833

Comment: yeah I did. Like i said , my custom template tag works just fine. Only issue is with jsonify which i installed using pip. That too works fine in my local env

Comment: After installing **jsonify** did you added that package inside your **requirements.txt** file ? because Heroku installes all available packages from **requirements.txt**  file and if any dependency is missing than your application will crash

Comment: Yes I did add jsonify to requiements.txt

Comment: can you provide screen shot or code of  full traceback

Answer (score 0):

jsonify is a function in Flask's flask. JSON module.
I recommend to use JsonResponse built-in function of Django.
Or just

Comment: (a) `jsonify` also exists as a [standalone library](https://pypi.org/project/jsonify/). (b) Can you provide more information about `JsonResponse`? (c) "Or just"… what? Please read [answer].