# Issue while deploying django site on AWS (TemplateSyntaxError)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I manage to deploy my site on AWS using NGINX and Gunicorn. The site was working fine but not I noticed there's an error when I visit the page. Can anyone guide me on what went wrong? here's the live site link: http://ec2-3-16-152-98.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: does this work in your local, share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, it's working fine on local. It was working fine on live too i just try to upload few new template files through SFTP and then this happens.

Comment: Try to restart the server, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686201/django-1-10-1-my-templatetag-is-not-a-registered-tag-library-must-be-one-of)