'custom_filters' is not a registered tag library
I'm creating a custom template filter to use in my Django template. The purpose of the filter is to access a dictionary value by key from within the template. I followed the standard procedure of defining the filter in a file inside a templatetags directory within my Django app:
'custom_filters' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz

My folder structure:
stream/
    ├── templatetags/
        └── __init__.py
        └── custom_filters.py

    ├── templates/
        └── index.html

My index.html:
{% load custom_filters %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Newspaper results</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css">
</head>

<body>

// HTML CODES

</body>
</html>

my custom_filters.py:
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)

my setting.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sslserver',
    'stream',    
]


Is stream in INSTALLED_APPS?

@willeM_VanOnsem, yes it is, I am going to edit my question.

Can you check the solutions mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686201/django-1-10-1-my-templatetag-is-not-a-registered-tag-library-must-be-one-of

Please restart the Django server and test again.
If that doesn't work, recheck the following steps.

Check App Registration: Ensure your stream app is correctly listed in the INSTALLED_APPS.
__init__.py in templatetags Directory: Ensure the templatetags directory has an __init__.py file to be recognized as a valid Python package.
Template Filter Loading: Ensure you're loading the template filter using `{% load custom_filters %| at the top of the template.

I hope this will help you a little. Let me know in the comments if it still doesn't work.
